# Java Selenium WebDriver указать путь до элемента

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Мне нужно проверить текст ошибки, которая выдается после не заполненного / не правильно заполненного поля

У меня не получается указать путь до элемента input_error (на странице может быть еще десяток таких)

```
<div class="form_controls">
  <input id="email" class="input_text" type="text" name="email">
  <div class="input_error">Укажите email</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<WebElement> inputs = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='form_controls']/div[@class='input_error']"));
```

Советую почитать [тут](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp), [тут](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted) , [тут](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html) и любой запрос в гугле типа `selenium java example` / `селениум примеры java`

Comment: первую ссылку я уже видел, по вашему примеру пути я пытался занести в переменню текст "Укажите email" String errorMail = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='form_controls']/div[@class='input_error']")).getText(); но мне выдает ошибку что не может найти элемент

Comment: Ну значит надо по-другому искать элемент. Смотрите, что у него уникального, и тогда уже указывайте этот xpath/class/id и т.д и т.п.

Comment: уникален id который идет над нужным классом и for

Comment: какой for? Вы имели в виду класс form_controls ?

Comment: оказалось все очень просто... я мог найти элемент, просто тест отрабатывал раньше, чем он успевал появиться... я добавил ожидание до появления элемента и теперь все проходит.

Comment: Почитай тогда про использование webdriver wait, тебе это пригодится